# (MIUI 9.5) got "waiting for wifi" when tried to install apps using mobile data

Tags: google-play-store, miui

How to download from Google Play without Wi-Fi setup ? I always got "waiting for wifi" when tried to install apps using mobile data.

Untick download using Wi-Fi doesn't help. BTW, I'm using MIUI 9.5 Chinese stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded then install the latest version of Google Play Store from [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/), After the installation, the problem is gone!

However, I still don't know why Playstore couldn't update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Play Store-> Settings -> App Download Preference and select 'Over any network'